# 2 Threads are started at once in java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

this is my first time asking question here..

i'm making an application which sends a sms to client when his computer turns off..

so far i'm able to receive the socket connection from client and when the client disconnects for first time it sends sms but if internet goes down and when client is connected again 2 threads are started instead of one..

here is the Server Side Coding

```
// Server class
public class server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // server is listening on port 5056
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(9000);

    // running infinite loop for getting
    // client request
    while (true) {
        Socket s = null;

        try {
            // socket object to receive incoming client requests
            s = ss.accept();

            System.out.println("A new client is connected : " + s);

            // obtaining input and out streams
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            System.out.println("Assigning new thread for this client");

            // create a new thread object
            Thread t = new ClientHandler(s, dis, dos);

            // Invoking the start() method
            t.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            s.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}

// ClientHandler class
class ClientHandler extends Thread {

DateFormat fordate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
DateFormat fortime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
final DataInputStream dis;
final DataOutputStream dos;
final Socket s;
public String received;
public static String mobile, left, name, uuid, smsrem, smsremafter;
public static int length, firstchar, length2, intsmsrem, intsmsremafter;
public static String receivedd;

// Constructor
public ClientHandler(Socket s, DataInputStream dis, DataOutputStream dos) {
    this.s = s;
    this.dis = dis;
    this.dos = dos;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    String received;
    String toreturn;
    while (true) {
        try {

            // Ask user what he wants
//i dont want to ask
            // receive the answer from client
            received = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println(received);
            if (received.equals("Exit")) {
                System.out.println("Client " + this.s + " sends exit...");
                System.out.println("Closing this connection.");
                this.s.close();
                System.out.println("Connection closed");
                break;
            }

            receivedd = received;
            mobile = received.substring(0, 10);
            length = received.length();
            left = received.substring(11, length);
            firstchar = left.indexOf("~");
            length2 = left.length();
            name = left.substring(0, firstchar);
            uuid = left.substring(firstchar + 1, length2);

            System.out.println(mobile);
            System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(uuid);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                //Client disconnect

                System.out.println("sms sent to " + mobile);
                System.out.println("sms decrease for" + uuid);
                s.close();
                break;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ClientHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    try {
        // closing resources
        this.dis.close();
        this.dos.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

and here is the client side coding.

```
              // Client class
       public class client 
       {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
      String home = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String name = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(home + "\\miningmajdur\\common\\tamilper.txt")));
    String mobile = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(home + "\\miningmajdur\\common\\tamilnokud.txt")));
    String uid = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(home + "\\miningmajdur\\common\\duke.txt")));
    try
    {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        // getting localhost ip
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");

        // establish the connection with server port 5056
        Socket s = new Socket(ip, 9000);

        // obtaining input and out streams
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        // the following loop performs the exchange of
        // information between client and client handler
        while (true) 
        {

             String tosend = ("2222222222" + "~" + name + "~" + uid);
                dos.writeUTF(tosend);


            // If client sends exit,close this connection 
            // and then break from the while loop
            if(tosend.equals("Exit"))
            {
                System.out.println("Closing this connection : " + s);
                s.close();
                System.out.println("Connection closed");
                break;
            }

            // printing date or time as requested by client
            String received = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println(received);
        }

        // closing resources
        scn.close();
        dis.close();
        dos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

this is where the on a multi threads start with single connection

```
A new client is connected : Socket[addr=/192.168.56.1,port=51447,localport=9000]
Assigning new thread for this client
no of threads ---------------3
A new client is connected : Socket[addr=/192.168.56.1,port=51446,localport=9000]
Assigning new thread for this client
no of threads ---------------4
A new client is connected : 
Socket[addr=/192.168.56.1,port=51448,localport=9000]
Assigning new thread for this client
no of threads ---------------5
A new client is connected : Socket[addr=/192.168.56.1,port=51450,localport=9000]
Assigning new thread for this client
```

Comment: Your output shows multiple client connections. Your client code shows a single connection. Either you ran the client multiple times or this isn't the real code. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: this indeed a real code..i run client only one time but more than one thread is started

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain some list at server side and need to check for duplicate request each time when you received a connect request

Comment: yes going to try this.will update once i get this working.

Answer (score 0):

i got the thing working..

i used Thread.interrupt to close any existing thread by putting the thread name in vector and check if any existing thread and if exist close other..